# How to access the query parameter(username or token) which is passed from iframe inside the bot?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, botframework, chatbot

I have node bot and the website which is developed in react. I put the iframe code inside the react and I am passing the username and token as below.

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/<conname>?s=<secret>&username=koushik'></iframe>
```

How to access the user name inside my bot? My bot is developed in node. The sample bot which I am using is teams-auth.
[git Link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/46.teams-auth)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using postMessage.

[Read this[Window.postmessage] for better understanding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with the embedded iframe version of web chat. You will want to use the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#bot-framework-web-chat) front-end client which allows for customizing and provides a rich tool set to work with. There are a lot of samples demonstrating a variety of methods to enable interactions between the web chat instance and your bot. It's a relatively easy setup and will allow for retrieving query parameters and passing them to your bot.

Hope of help!

Comment: Still the issue is not resolved , How to access the query data inside the bot?